# How to set first full row as a index in big data using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I want to delete the row index(Country 0 1 2 3 4.....) and want to make a first row(0 1800 1801 1802 1803........) as an index. so how can I do this? please let me know if anyone has the answer to this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter `header=[1]` for set columns names by second row of file:

```
rd = pd.read_csv('afganistan.csv', index_col=[0], header=[1])
```

Or use `skiprows=1` for skippping first row in file:

```
rd = pd.read_csv('afganistan.csv', index_col=[0], skiprows=1)
```

EDIT:

It seems for also avoid first values for index (0,1,2..) and set index by `country` columns, then is necessary use:

```
rd = pd.read_csv('afganistan.csv', index_col=[1], header=[1]).iloc[:, 1:]
```

Or:

```
rd = pd.read_csv('afganistan.csv', index_col=[1], skiprows=1).iloc[:, 1:]
```